# How to I call an api and display information from it in a Label on Xamrin.iOS?

Tags: api, xamarin, xamarin.ios, label

I am completely stuck, and I have been searching for days,
It probably doesn't help that I am a complete and total noob.
All of the apis that I call in web reference give me this in the little preview box:

```
WebMissingResource
-WebDiscoRefReport
-Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.
-WebDiscoRefReport
-WebDiscoRefReport
```

I am sure it is something stupid and really easy for the regular C#-er.
But I am not, and apologize in advance. If anyone knows of a video explaining such, feel free to send it, as I am not coming up with any results, but maybe I am searching for the wrong thing.
Thanks

EDIT: API I am trying to call: https://chasing-coins.com/api/v1/convert/BTC/USD

Comment: there are LOTS of different kinds of web services.  What specifically are you trying to call?

Comment: Hey. I am trying to call this api here: https://chasing-coins.com/api/v1/convert/BTC/USD

Comment: that appears to be a simple REST service: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/consuming/rest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be pretty easy!

All you have to do is call the api from your view controller asynchronously and wait for the api server to send a response back. This will most likely come back in the form of a JSON object and C# has lots of great libraries for storing and manipulating JSON data (most notably Newtonsoft.JSON)

Once you get the data back, store it as a JSON object and then pass whatever information to the label that you would like to display.

It might look something like this:(be sure to include Newtonsoft.Json.Linq)

```
JObject joResponse = JObject.Parse(responseFromAPICall);
MyLabel.Text = joResponse.Coin
```

The code above would take the api response and put it into a usable JSON object. From there, you can access each part of the response like you were accessing any other member from a class object. Above we access the Coin type and pass it to the label

Hope this helps!